# C++: warning: instantiation of variable 'Lista<Vehiculo>::finLista' required here, but no definition is available

Tags: c++, variables, template, static

soy nuevo en la comunidad y estoy empezando con C++.

Lo que pretendo hacer es, antes de aprender las listas propias del C++, es crear mi propia:
`template <typename T> class Lista`. Para ello tengo un archivo *lista.h* .Lo hago para experimentar un poco con el código.

He creado otra clase `Vehiculo`, en dos archivos, *vehiculo.h* y *vehiculo.cpp*, para ir detallando tipos de vehículo e introducirlos en la lista. Es decir quiero que en este caso mi lista sea de objetos. Pero creo que este inciso es lo de menos.

Dicho todo esto voy al grano, entre las muchas opciones que barajé para construir la lista se me ocurrió poner dos variables estáticas:

```
  static Lista *inicioLista;
  static Lista *finLista;
```

Cuando quiero dar valores a estas variables desde el `main()`, en el archivo *main.cpp*, me sale el *warning* del título, y dos errores,

C++ error: undefined reference to `Lista::inicioLista' 
C++ error: undefined reference to `Lista::finLista' .

Dejo a continuación el código relevante:

lista.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
template <typename T>
class Lista{

private:
    T *item;
    Lista *siguiente;

public:

    static Lista *inicioLista;
    static Lista *finLista;

    Lista(){

    }
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "vehiculo.h"
#include "lista.h"

int main(){

    Lista <Vehiculo> *lista = new Lista<Vehiculo>();

    Lista<Vehiculo>::finLista = nullptr;
    Lista<Vehiculo>::inicioLista = lista;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Normalmente estas cosas las arreglo *googleando*, y mirando algún lugar de referencia, pero en esta ocasión no sé ni por qué no va. Lo cual me ha dejado sorprendido. Recurro a la comunidad para ver dónde está el problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás usando una sintaxis incorrecta. Para instanciar variables-miembro estáticas de plantillas, se hace así:

```
template< typename T > Lista *Lista< T >::inicioLista = nullptr;
template< typename T > Lista *Lista< T >::finLista = nullptr;
```

Además, ha de estar disponible **antes** de la instanciación de la plantilla que las use, de ahí el aviso que obtienes: En tu ejemplo, estás instanciando las variables estáticas **despues** de instanciar tu plantilla.

Si bien las variables-miembro estáticas solo admiten 1 instaciación (de ahí que se suelan realizar en archivos `.cpp`), al tratarse de plantillas, el enlazador *nos hace el favor* de descartar las copias de mas, por lo que es perfectamente posible instanciar en archivos de cabecera:

```
// lista.h

template< typename T > class Lista {
    static Lista *inicioLista;
    static Lista *finLista;

    ...
};

template< typename T > Lista *Lista< T >::inicioLista = nullptr;
template< typename T > Lista *Lista< T >::finLista = nullptr;
```

Comment: Buenas @Juanjo!! Ahora trabaja  y puedo seguir probando.Gracias por todo.
Por otro lado no fue fácil encontrar la solución. A ver si le sirve a más personas.
Saludos

Comment: Increíble, dejó de servir y he tenido que poner una <T> a mayores de la siguiente forma:
`template<typename T>Lista<T> *Lista<T>::inicioLista = nullptr;`
Lógicamente lo he añadido a `finLista` también.